# Run Multi Program With Delay in batch file

Tags: batch-file

i want run a program and then close that program after 30 sec.

i write a two batch files ,

first batch file is running the program. the program is Hotspot Shield.

the cod is

```
@ECHO off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Hotspot Shield\bin\hsscp.exe"
timeout /t 30
"E:\1.bat"
Exit
```

the program is running fine, but after 30 Second the second batch file won't running .

the code of second batch file is

```
@ECHO off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Hotspot Shield\bin"
Taskkill /IM "hsscp.exe" /F
Exit
```

when i add this command

```
timeout /t 30
```

before the this command in first batch file

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Hotspot Shield\bin\hsscp.exe"
```

the batch file counting down . but after that not counting down.

what is the problem?

i just want run the hotspot shield and after 30 second close that.
windows is 10.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ECHO off
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Hotspot Shield\bin\hsscp.exe"
timeout /t 30 >NUL
Taskkill /IM "hsscp.exe" /F
Exit
```

The `...hsscp.exe` executable will start in a new process. The 30-second timeout will become silent because of the `>nul` and the current directory for `taskkill` is not relevant.

The first double-quoted argument in a `start` command is the window-title, so the extra pair of quotes in the `start` command provides an empty title.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's still true but the Hotspot Shield executable used to accept a `-quit` parameter. If that's the case then it would surely be a better option than forcibly closing it with `TaskKill`.

This may well be worth a try:

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Hotspot Shield\bin" 2>Nul || Exit /B
Start hsscp
Timeout 30 /NoBreak > Nul
Start hsscp -quit
```